# Convert entire folder to grayscale using image magick?

Tags: image, batch-file, grayscale

Another person asked this question but the answers are not adjusted to the average civilian comprehension.

I am trying to convert an entire folder to grayscale, using image magick.

I want to convert the entire folder of JPG and PNG images that are in color to grayscale.

Things that I know: I know to open notepad, copy-paste text aka code, save it as a bat, save it in a specific folder, and click run.

Anything beyond what is listed is not within my skills.

I see here on this website a million questions that I also have but answers are not end-user friendly. For example, no one mentioned that we can't have folder names with spaces in the Run command line window.

Codes are not full but in fragments throughout messages and there is no conclusion at the end when the problem is solved that gives step-by-step procedure on how to solve the problem.

Can anyone help with the full code I need to have in notepad for the batch procedure to work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for Notepad. Start a Command Prompt and change directory to the one containing your images. So if your images are in `HOME/Images`, type:

```
cd Images
```

then press `Enter/Return`. Then type:

```
magick mogrify -colorspace gray *.png *.jpg
```

then press `Enter/Return` and you're finished.

Comment: Thank you.
"Start a Command Prompt and change directory" How do I do this?
C:\Users\Name> 
is on the screen and when I type folder location I get "The syntax of the command is incorrect." or "The system cannot find the path specified." or "'Desktop' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: What directory (folder) are your images in, please?

Comment: For people in the future reading this, the easiest way is to have folder on desktop with one word name and all photos you want to convert to grayscale inside. When you open the command prompt it will have this on first line "C:\Users\Name" in order to get to your folder you have type cd desktop, and then cd foldername. So the letters cd space and folder name will get you to have that in command line. Once you are there you copy the code magick mogrify -colorspace gray *.png *.jpg and click enter. Nothing will be visible on screen but images will turn to grayscale in that folder.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping. I figured the cd thingy to get to the specific folder. I was confused since nothing was happening but then I realized images are becoming grayscale in the folder. It looks like it is working. Thank you, truly. I was going crazy with knowing it should be easy but I just do not have brain power IT to decode the answers on this site.